# Floats in CSS - Gap/space left on top when floated to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is a little difficult to describe, but basically there is undesired space left by a floated div on my page. Here are pictures describing the problem. The black boxes are divs.

Before floating:

[image]

After floating:

[image]

Desired effect:

[image]

And I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I also have an empty div with "clear: both" placed immediately after the floated div.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could we see the CSS and HTML that are causing this problem?

Comment: I tried floating both divs but that didn't solve my problem right away. The problem was that there was a rogue div (unfloated) hanging out in between, still causing the same effect as above. After moving this div inside of the left-most one, I was able to achieve the proper effect.

The answer marked below was the one that helped me figure it out. Thanks for the answers everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="a1">a1</div>
<div class="a2">a2</div>

.a1
{
 background-color:Red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
float:left; 
}
.a2
{
  background-color:Green;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
}
```

=======try this

Answer (score 8):

If possible, put the `float: right` `div` before the unfloated `div` in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the clearing div. Also check the padding/margin on those divs and ensure that the containing div (parent div) is wide enough to accommodate the two child divs.

Answer (score 3):

The first `div` should have `float: left` set. Else the first div, which is a block element, will take up all the vertical space for itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
HTML
<div id="container">
   <div id="main">
     blah blah blah blah blah
   </div>
   <div id="aside">
   this goes to the side
   </div>
   <div id="clear"></div>
</div>

CSS
div#container
{
    width : 80%;//your preference
    height : auto;
    margin : 0 auto;//Centers the page
}

div#main
{
    width : 70%;
    height : auto;
    display : block;//to wrap it up inside its width
    float : left;//float it towards left
}

div#aside
{
    width : 30%;//take up rest of the width size
    height : auto;
    display : block;
    float :right;//float towards right
}

#clear
{
    clear : both;//this will do the job
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is youre only floating one div. You need to make the margin-right on the non foated div the same width as the total space (width+paddding+margin) of the floated div.

Or alternatiely you can float both divs.

Examples:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 410px;">
<div style="float: right; width: 200px;">
  <p> Right div</p>
</div>
<div style="width: 200px; margin-right: 210px;">
  <p> Left Div</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

OR:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 410px;">

<div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 10px;">
  <p> Left Div</p>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
  <p> Right div</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both divs should float left and make sure they equal or are less than the width of the container they are in.

Answer (score 0):

If a1 is to appear floated to the right of a2, then you have to put a1 FIRST in the html, and float it right.  A bit counter intuitive, but its how floats work.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a1">a1</div>
  <div class="a2">a2</div>
</div>
<style>
div
{
  border: solid 2px #000;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.a1
{
 background-color:Red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
float:right; /* the trick is, a1 appears BEFORE a2 in the html, yet
we are floating a1 right .  if you do it the other way around
( try and float a2 ) then it will work like you showed
(separate line)*/
}
.a2
{
  background-color:Green;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  /* don't float this one */

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a white space issue with floats. That's why the second box is slightly lower.

```
<div style="float:left">a1</div><div style="float:left">a2</div>
```

will work.

```
<div style="float:left">a1</div>
<div style="float:left">a2</div>
```

won't work